# How to print 2D Arrays to look like a grid/matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I'm trying to print Sudoku like grids. The desire output would be:

```
    int [][] easyGrid = {{2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6},
                                    {4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5},
                                    {8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1},
                                    {1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3},
                                    {7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8},
                                    {3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7},
                                    {6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9},
                                    {9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4},
                                    {5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2}}

;
```

But with `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(easyGrid));` I get something like

```
[[2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6], [4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5], [8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1], [1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3], [7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8], [3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7], [6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9], [9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4], [5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way might be to use a combination of `StringJoiner` (Java 8+) and `String.format`, for example

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] easyGrid = {
            {2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6},
            {4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5},
            {8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1},
            {1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3},
            {7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8},
            {3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7},
            {6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9},
            {9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4},
            {5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2}};
        for (int[] row : easyGrid) {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" | ");
            for (int col : row) {
                sj.add(String.format("%02d", col));
            }
            System.out.println(sj.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
02 | 03 | 05 | 09 | 07 | 01 | 08 | 04 | 06
04 | 07 | 01 | 02 | 08 | 06 | 09 | 03 | 05
08 | 09 | 06 | 04 | 03 | 05 | 02 | 07 | 01
01 | 06 | 08 | 07 | 04 | 09 | 05 | 02 | 03
07 | 04 | 09 | 05 | 02 | 03 | 01 | 06 | 08
03 | 05 | 02 | 01 | 06 | 08 | 04 | 09 | 07
06 | 02 | 04 | 08 | 01 | 07 | 03 | 05 | 09
09 | 01 | 03 | 06 | 05 | 02 | 07 | 08 | 04
05 | 08 | 07 | 03 | 09 | 04 | 06 | 01 | 02
```

You can generate some very complex results with these.  Have a look at [formatted strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] easyGrid = {
            {2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6},
            {4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5},
            {8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1},
            {1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3},
            {7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8},
            {3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7},
            {6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9},
            {9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4},
            {5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2}};
        String lineSplit = "";
        StringJoiner splitJoiner = new StringJoiner("+", "|", "|");
        for (int index = 0; index < easyGrid[0].length; index++) {
            splitJoiner.add(String.format("%4s", "").replace(" ", "-"));
        }
        lineSplit = splitJoiner.toString();
        for (int[] row : easyGrid) {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" | ", "| ", " |");
            for (int col : row) {
                sj.add(String.format("%02d", col));
            }
            System.out.println(lineSplit);
            System.out.println(sj.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
    }

}
```

Which outputs

```
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 02 | 03 | 05 | 09 | 07 | 01 | 08 | 04 | 06 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 04 | 07 | 01 | 02 | 08 | 06 | 09 | 03 | 05 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 08 | 09 | 06 | 04 | 03 | 05 | 02 | 07 | 01 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 01 | 06 | 08 | 07 | 04 | 09 | 05 | 02 | 03 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 07 | 04 | 09 | 05 | 02 | 03 | 01 | 06 | 08 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 03 | 05 | 02 | 01 | 06 | 08 | 04 | 09 | 07 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 06 | 02 | 04 | 08 | 01 | 07 | 03 | 05 | 09 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 09 | 01 | 03 | 06 | 05 | 02 | 07 | 08 | 04 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
| 05 | 08 | 07 | 03 | 09 | 04 | 06 | 01 | 02 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----|
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_deeptostring.htm says:

> The java.util.Arrays.deepToString(Object[]) method returns a string
>   representation of the "deep contents" of the specified array. If the
>   array contains other arrays as elements, the string representation
>   contains their contents and so on. This method is designed for
>   converting multidimensional arrays to strings. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in
>   square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the
>   characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).

The solution is you have to cut the array in the 2d array, then you continuous cut every number in this array. After that, you print all the number in each array you cut. This is exactly what you need:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] easyGrid = {{2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6},
                {4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5},
                {8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1},
                {1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3},
                {7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8},
                {3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7},
                {6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9},
                {9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4},
                {5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2}};
        for(int[] arr : easyGrid) {
            for(int number: arr) {
                System.out.print(number + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea to use one of the printing methods from the `Arrays` class.  However, with `Arrays.deepToString()`, you end up with a one-liner output, which is not what you want.  Instead, you can iterate over the rows of your two-dimensional array and use `Arrays.toString()` on each row:

```
for (int i=0; i < easyGrid[0].length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(easyGrid[i]));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 9, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6]
[4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5]
[8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1]
[1, 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3]
[7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8]
[3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7]
[6, 2, 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5, 9]
[9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4]
[5, 8, 7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2]
```